# voice integration in Django website

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new to Django, is there any app for voice communication in django. Like on going to the main url of the site, site will say "Welcome to main page". After login, site will say "Hello ".

Basically I am creating monitoring website, so my purpose is to check for issues, and if any issue comes, voice app will speak the issue details.

I am able to build few portions of monitoring website, now looking for voice app but not able to find suitable app for voice integration after lot of googling as well :(

I have build exes with this voice feature using pyttsx3, so similar app like pyttsx3 in django.

Thanks

Comment: maybe [Twilio API](https://www.twilio.com/), but not sure for this **[if any issue comes, voice app will speak the issue details]**

Comment: @Lemayzeur : thanks for the reply, basically what i am thinking is.. voice app will continuously listen to worker queue and different django web-apps will push statements to the worker queue whenever any issue is reported. voice app will pop record from worker queue and covert that statement into voice and will speak immediately. Is it something doable through django ?

Comment: obviously django does ... but the most important is to find the compatible python module, All the logics will be done with python. Django as a web Framework, will handle and display